# Cufon not Working on SSL?

Tags: javascript, ssl, canvas, cufon

i have bought SSL for my server and installed it. But after i install, i figured out that cufon is not working anymore. I've checked some questions and i've googled but none of the solutions worked.

Added the codes in footer to header exc., tried everything but not working, thanks for your replies.

Header :

```
<script src="http://cufon.shoqolate.com/js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/js/myriad-pro.cufonfonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Footer :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Cufon.now(); 
Cufon.replace('.myriad_pro_semibold', { fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro Semibold', hover: true }); 
Cufon.replace('.myriad_pro_bold', { fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro Bold', hover: true }); 
Cufon.replace(
    'h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .menu-title',
    { fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro Bold' }
);
Cufon.replace('.nav a, .nav2', { fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro Semibold', hover: true }); </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried downloading the `cufon-yui.js` to your own server and serve it from there? You are currently fetching it from `http` not `https` which both breaks the whole purpose of using `https` since that connection is not secure and might be the thing that makes the script not even load.

Comment: Then accept the answer that I just added when you are able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried downloading the `cufon-yui.js` to your own server and serve it from there? You are currently fetching it from `http` not `https` which both breaks the whole purpose of using `https` since that connection is not secure and might be the thing that makes the script not even load.

Answer (score 0):

Some scripts like jquery from google servers can be served as protocol agnostic (meaning they will use https if the parent page is using https)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, it looks like cufon doesn't have https on their servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following link instead of cufon.shoqolate.com.
    `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cufon/1.09i/cufon-yui.js`

Infact, the cufon url automatically redirects to this asd